# error :array cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-resources

Initially I was getting values in the array. Now I am getting error.  Array cannot be resolved or is not a field in java code. Unable to resolve.

Java code :

```
String[] categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories_for_homemain);
```

xml code string.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
           <string-array name="categories_for_homemain">
           <item>one</item>
           <item>two</item>
           <item>three</item>
           <item>four</item>
           <item>five</item>
           <item>six</item>
           <item>seven</item>   
           </string-array>
       </resources>
```

Comment: did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: Do you see any logcat?

Comment: try `R.string.categories_for_homemain`

Comment: where you try this code? in activity or fragment? post your complete code

Comment: just clean your project and restart the IDE :)

Comment: yes cleaned project. not working

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure you have imported the right `R` class. it is a common phenomenon to import `android.R` instead of your project's `R.`
2. after checking 1, clean and rebuild your appl